# How to Sign in a domain of Ubuntu Server from Windows XP?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2003, domain, samba

I've got a a problem, I've got an Ubuntu server 13.10 with samba and a domain, in the network I use 2 Windows XP as clients, which I have added to the domain. When I want to sign in the domain as root in Windows XP, a error message appears saying that the domain is not available.

I have also checked the logs of `/var/logs/syslog` in Ubuntu server, this appears:

> error (network unreachable) resolving 'mpa.one.microsoft.com/A/IN :192.58.128.30#53

And more errors like this. I've also created and tested samba users, and entered in the domain with SWAT.

Both computers can reach ping. The server IP is `192.168.1.1` and the XP IP is `192.168.1.4`.
I would like to log in in the XP computer, but with a samba or Ubuntu account in the domain (like root...).

Comment: You really should move away from XP. [Support for it has ended](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx) quite some time now, and you are becoming increasingly more vulnerable each day you stay on XP.

Comment: I know that XP is very vulnerable and that I should move to 7/8, but I have to do it with XP for work reasons, and I don´t know how to solve this problem... Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your problem appears to be with WGA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908440) (Windows Genuine Advantage validation/anti-piracy).  `mpa.one.microsoft.com` is one of the domains used by this DRM scheme, and an error message saying that domain can't be reached strongly suggests that a failure to reach this domain is causing the XP clients to kill the connection you're trying to make.

So, your first (and hopefully only) step to resolving this would be to makes sure traffic to and from your network is allowed to and from the domains used for WGA, which are listed in the Microsoft KB I linked.